# Proceeding to back to userform to make correction

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have code that I want to check to make sure that the barcodes entered using a userform is valid and it is available to be sold. My problem is after it finishes checking, it does not allow me to make edits on the userform anymore.

I have designed the code for each line of item.

```
Private Sub PriceTextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    Dim bccs1 As String
    Dim bcce1 As String
    bccs1 = BarcodeStartNumber1TextBox.Text
    bcce1 = BarcodeEndNumber1TextBox.Text
    MsgBox ("Please wait for a few moment while the barcodes are validated.")
    On Error GoTo bccErrorHandler1
    If DescriptionTextBox1.Text = "Deep Penetrating Sealant (DPS)" _
                Or DescriptionTextBox1.Text = "Top Seal (TS)" Then
        Sheets("Inventory Log").Select
        Columns("J:J").Select
        Selection.Find(what:=bccs1, after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, MatchByte:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        Do
            If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "In" Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Out" Then
                MsgBox ("Barcode" & ActiveCell.Value & " has already been sold")
                If ActiveCell = bbce1 Then Exit Do
                MsgBox ("The barcode batch " & bccs1 & " to " & bcce1 & _
                    " are available")
            End If
        Loop
    End If
bbccErrorHandler1:
    MsgBox ("The barcode you have entered is invalid. Please check entry.")
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `bbccErrorHandler1` will run whether there is an error or not, and that the `Exit Sub` is redundant immediately before `End Sub`. The `Exit Sub` is probably better located just before `bbccErrorHandler1:`.  (That issue was easier to see one the code was properly indented/spaced.)

Comment: You are likely have fallen in an endless loop. If the value in column K is not "In" then you keep looping and checking the same cell. If the value in the cell is neither "Out" then you will not even notice it, just the Form or Excel freeze.

Comment: I know it is complicated and this is the only way I know how to do it. Probably I will just disregard this and tell user to manually make sure that the barcodes are available before they issue the invoice. I used the same code just to check the barcodes.